# How does spring inject arguments into the controller method

Tags: java, spring

```
public ModelAndView loginPage(HttpServletRequest request, Locale locale) {}
```

As you know, Spring injects `HttpServletRequest` and `Locale` into the method. I want to know
how is it done behind the curtains ? My guess is, there is a data converter system working behind
that takes http request headers and body data and fill them into the suitable classes that are given 
in arguments by the coder. Am I right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're right.  In short, there is a single entry point into the application (there may be more than one entry point) that routes incoming traffic, passing incoming data to methods as parameters.  This is known as the front controller pattern.

Spring's `DispatcherServlet` is an implementation of the front controller pattern. The Spring reference [details the pattern](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-servlet) as followed in Spring, and the pattern is listed among the [core Java EE patterns](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/frontcontroller-135648.html).

Answer (score 2):

When working with Spring MVC there are multiple parts moving to solve the problem of mapping `HandlerMapping` and execution `HandlerAdapter`.

Each `@Controller` is scanned for `@RequestMapping` annotated methods, the methods are mapped to URLs based on the metadata available in the `@RequestMapping` annotation, this is done by the [`RequestMappingHandlerMapping`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html) class.

When a request comes in the specific method is matched on the incoming request. This selected method is passed the [`RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.html) which consults all method arguments. The actual handling of the method argument is left to different [`HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodArgumentResolver.html) implementations (you could also implement your own).

The same happens for the return value of your method although that is delegated to a [`HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/support/HandlerMethodReturnValueHandler.html).